# How to extract data from the soup in the absence of an opening tag?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get PDFs info from [Wikimedia Commons PDF-gallery](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:%E0%AE%85%E0%AE%B5%E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%B5%E0%AF%88_%E0%AE%A4%E0%AE%BF._%E0%AE%95._%E0%AE%9A%E0%AE%A3%E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%AE%E0%AF%81%E0%AE%95%E0%AE%AE%E0%AF%8D). I successfully extracted the PDF's title. But unable to get its **pages** and its **size** from there.Because there is no opening tag of `<br>` but the closing tag `<br/>` is present.

My Code ;-

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

bookUrl= u'https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:அவ்வை தி. க. சண்முகம்'
#print (bookUrl)
bookContent = requests.get(bookUrl).content
bookSoup = BeautifulSoup(bookContent,'lxml')
bookdataSummary1 = bookSoup.findAll(id='mw-content-text')
for div in bookdataSummary1:
    liAll = div.findAll('li')
    for li in liAll:
        pdfAllData1 = li.find('div',{'class':'gallerytext'})
        print(pdfAllData1)
        aOnly = pdfAllData1.find('a')
        print(aOnly['title'])
        break
```

The output;-

```
    <div class="gallerytext">
    <a class="galleryfilename galleryfilename-truncate" href="/wiki/File:%E0%AE%8E%E0%AE%A9%E0%AE%A4%E0%AF%81_%E0%AE%A8%E0%AE%BE%E0%AE%9F%E0%AE%95%E0%AE%B5%E0%AE%BE%E0%AE%B4%E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%95%E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%95%E0%AF%88.pdf" title="File:எனது நாடகவாழ்க்கை.pdf">எனது நாடகவாழ்க்கை.pdf</a>
    819 × 1,236, 569 pages; 39.7 MB<br/>
    </div>

File:எனது நாடகவாழ்க்கை.pdf
```

The needed output;-

```
title="File:எனது நாடகவாழ்க்கை.pdf">எனது நாடகவாழ்க்கை.pdf</a>
        819 × 1,236, 569 pages; 39.7 MB<br/>
```

How to extract the data inbetween the closing tags? That is `</a>` and `<br/>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways you can get the text you want.

## Using [`.contents`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children) property

You can use `.contents` to get the required content from a tag. If you check the contents of the `div` tag (`print(soup.div.contents)`), you'll get this output:

```
['\n', <a class="galleryfilename galleryfilename-truncate" href="/wiki/File:%E0%AE%8E%E0%AE%A9%E0%AE%A4%E0%AF%81_%E0%AE%A8%E0%AE%BE%E0%AE%9F%E0%AE%95%E0%AE%B5%E0%AE%BE%E0%AE%B4%E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%95%E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%95%E0%AF%88.pdf" title="File:எனது நாடகவாழ்க்கை.pdf">எனது நாடகவாழ்க்கை.pdf</a>, '\n    819 × 1,236, 569 pages; 39.7 MB', <br/>, '\n']
```

From here, you can see that the required content is available in the 3rd position (2nd index). To get that, you can use this:

```
html = '''<div class="gallerytext">
<a class="galleryfilename galleryfilename-truncate" href="/wiki/File:%E0%AE%8E%E0%AE%A9%E0%AE%A4%E0%AF%81_%E0%AE%A8%E0%AE%BE%E0%AE%9F%E0%AE%95%E0%AE%B5%E0%AE%BE%E0%AE%B4%E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%95%E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%95%E0%AF%88.pdf" title="File:எனது நாடகவாழ்க்கை.pdf">எனது நாடகவாழ்க்கை.pdf</a>
    819 × 1,236, 569 pages; 39.7 MB<br/>
</div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
print(soup.find('div').contents[2].strip())
# 819 × 1,236, 569 pages; 39.7 MB
```

---

## Using [`NavigableString`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring)

```
info = ''.join([x.strip() for x in soup.find('div').contents if isinstance(x, NavigableString)])
print(info)
# 819 × 1,236, 569 pages; 39.7 MB
```

<sup>Don't forget to import this as `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString`</sup>

---

## Using [`.next_sibling`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling) property

And another way, is to use the .

```
a_tag = soup.find('div').a
print(a_tag)
# <a class="galleryfilename galleryfilename-truncate" href="/wiki/File:%E0%AE%8E%E0%AE%A9%E0%AE%A4%E0%AF%81_%E0%AE%A8%E0%AE%BE%E0%AE%9F%E0%AE%95%E0%AE%B5%E0%AE%BE%E0%AE%B4%E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%95%E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%95%E0%AF%88.pdf" title="File:எனது நாடகவாழ்க்கை.pdf">எனது நாடகவாழ்க்கை.pdf</a>
info = a_tag.next_sibling
print(info.strip())
# 819 × 1,236, 569 pages; 39.7 MB
```

---

## EDIT:

Using any one of the above techniques, you can get the content you want. All the PDFs are located inside a `<div class="gallerytext">` tag.

Complete code:

```
r = requests.get(u'https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:அவ்வை தி. க. சண்முகம்')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

for item in soup.find_all('div', class_='gallerytext'):
    a_tag = item.a
    print(a_tag['title'])  # or print(a_tag['href']) if you want the link
    info = a_tag.next_sibling.strip()
    print(info)
```

Output:

```
File:எனது நாடகவாழ்க்கை.pdf
819 × 1,236, 569 pages; 39.7 MB
File:தமிழ் நாடகத் தலைமை ஆசிரியர்-1.pdf
637 × 957, 40 pages; 3.61 MB
File:தமிழ் நாடகத் தலைமை ஆசிரியர்-2.pdf
612 × 963, 67 pages; 9.32 MB
File:நாடகக்கலை-1.pdf
639 × 996, 161 pages; 6.35 MB
File:நாடகக்கலை-2.pdf
673 × 954, 155 pages; 7.22 MB
File:நாடகச்சிந்தனைகள்.pdf
715 × 1,047, 133 pages; 5.17 MB
```

Comment: Works fine for a PDF. But the gallery contains 6 PDFs. (I am going to get nearly 2200 PDF's infos.) Kindly see my code. I am breaking the loop. if it continues, it is not easy to change the html (In contents property) for every PDF. How can i get all 6 PDFs infos.

Comment: Check the edit. I've added the full code to get the info and the title/hrefs of all PDFs.